# how get info from jira api on c#

Tags: c#, jira, jira-rest-api

I am writing an asp.net mvc application on c#, i have the task of writing a controller that receives data from JIRA via jira api,
I have a format link:

https://jira.xxx.ru/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=yyy

I know the login and password for connecting to jira, in the json response I get the following information:

"maxResults": x,
"total": x

can i just connect and return the necessary data to me in the containers, can someone have an example or tell me where can I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use RestClient Following code is I am use get issue from JIRA.

```
        private string RestCall()
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient(url + "/rest/api/2/search?jql=");
                var request = new RestRequest
                {
                    Method = Method.GET,
                    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
                };
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + api_token);
                var response = client.Execute(request);
                result = response.Content;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Here

```
 url: Base URL of you jira account

 api_token: JIRA API token generated from JIRA username and password
```

Comment: hi! @debug_dk
I got errors: for RestClient and RestRequest - could not find the type or name of the namespace, and for Method.GET and DataFormat.Json - do not exist in this context. What can be done about this? sorry for that, i only start to programming

Comment: Hi, for Method.Get and DataFormat.Json please add using RestSharp;

Comment: thx @debug_dk, its working, and can I see at the backend stage what data this controller returns, maybe through postman?

Answer (score 1):

//write this code into your controller and attach a view to its GetJiraProject method

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace Worklog2.Controllers
{
    public class JiraController : Controller
    {
        private string baseUrl = "https://xxxxxx.atlassian.net";
        private string UserName = "abc@gmail.io";
      private string Password = "ATATT3xFfGF0__LJW3SYJQhj7zKXlmbay6_PJu9ZmyK9AOxdlCQnS6zY_Dhyg2KWsDlxrNLdSMAbyWSYD7dxOUNdlswwy38PWdx4iILeTqBeBRq-QwMLk1tC9sMSzoO_HapCia3gF61DugB3CWensXWGLGmgWNt1MqOdAVwm_ILlpy87eho_tmQ=A9F58D0F";

        public static string GetEncodedCredentials(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            string mergedCredentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", UserName, Password);
            byte[] byteCredentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
        }

        public ActionResult GetJiraProject()
        {
            string restUrl = String.Format("{0}/rest/api/3/project", baseUrl);
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(restUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + GetEncodedCredentials(UserName, Password));

            using (response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                ViewBag.ResponseContent = responseContent;
            }

            return View();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?